# How to create an .etl file with a Data Collector Set

Tags: windows, perfmon

Was wondering how do you go about logging a Data Collector Set(Specifically a Trace Session) using PerfMon on Windows 11. I understand there's a shortcut to create a dump on a crash, but how do i generate a etl file on call.

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out how to do this; So thought i'd leave the steps I used for anyone searching in the future.

**1. Open PerfMon**

**2. Select the 'Data Collector Sets' folder option in the left hand pane**
->Following, Select the 'User Defined' Folder

**3.In the Action Pane above there will be an icon, furthest on the right resembling a window with a golden asterisk.**-> Click it to activate the wizard

**4.Follow the Wizard instructions**